# Putting query inside a for loop with condition in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is not duplicate but related to the topic [Query inside for loop in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237087/query-inside-for-loop-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment89453437_51237087)

Is this the correct code in laravel for putting query inside the loop

```
//controller
        public function dtrdata()
        {
            for($i=1;$i<=$totalnumdays;$i++){
                $query= DB::table('dtrrecords')
                ->where('dtrrecords.bio_id', $i)
            }
            return view('pages/admin.dtrdata', compact('query','i'));
        }
        //view
         @foreach($query as $row => $rows1)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$rows1->AM_IN}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: There is also `whereBetween`: `$query = DB::table('dtrrecords')->whereBetween(['bio_id', 1, $totalnumdays])->get();`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with your loop. First you are overwriting the `$query` variable on each iteration. Second, you need to call `->get()` to execute the query and return results. The following illustrates how to add multiple query results into a single collection and then loop the results in the view:

```
 public function dtrdata()
 {
     $collection = collect();
     for($i=1;$i<=$totalnumdays;$i++){
         $records = DB::table('dtrrecords')->where('dtrrecords.bio_id', $i)->get();
         $collection->concat($records)
     }
     return view('pages/admin.dtrdata', compact('collection'));
 }


 @foreach($collection as $item)
 <tr>
     <td>{{ $item->AM_IN} }</td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: there is no data showing when i use your code  as my reference maybe i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

You can do your job by another solution without looping:

```
public function dtrdata()
{
   // Make an array from 1 to $totalnumdays using php range function
   // follow the link for range function https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_range.asp
    $numDays = range(1,$totalnumdays);   
    $query= DB::table('dtrrecords')
        ->whereIn('dtrrecords.bio_id', $numDays)    // Use laravel whereIn method
        ->get();
    return view('pages/admin.dtrdata', compact('query'));
}
//view
 @foreach($query as $row => $rows1)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$rows1->AM_IN}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: your code seems to work, but i cannot use your code because i have data that need to be match in array this is the link of the code related to my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237087/query-inside-for-loop-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment89453437_51237087

because im relying on data that was inside of the array